# Kate: windows (instances) with different tabs, drag tabs to new window

Tags: kde, window, tabs

I want Kate's tabs to behave as in almost all other tabbed programs I use:

- When I open a new window, it opens in a new instance, without duplicating tabs from other open windows
- When I close a tab in a window, it is only closed in that window (not across all windows)
- When I drag a tab out of the window, a new window with that tab is opened
- When I drag a tab out of the window to another window, the tab is moved to that other window

I do not seem to be alone in that (see reddit question [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/szdqcr/question_about_kate_text_editor_how_to_close_file/), KDE forums question [here](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=152273)), but I have not found an answer yet. Is it straight up impossible? Because it's the reason I stopped using Kate previously, and I'd like to give it another try.

I'm on (K)ubuntu 22.04, using Kate 21.12.3.